# The matrix transformation $A$ to $AB - BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T\colon M_2(\Bbb R) \to M_2(\Bbb R)$ is the linear transformation that sends $A$ to $AB-BA$, and I want to find the dimension of the kernel of $T$. I have a way of doing this, but I'm not sure if it is correct, and I would like to know if there is a faster way.

I know that the kernel of $T$ will be the set of all matrices that satisfy the solution to

$AB-BA=0$ and therefore $AB=BA$

The solution could then be found by substituting variables in for the entries of $A$, and writing down four equations with four unknowns. You could then solve each equation for zero, and solve the homogeneous system through an augmented matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\b_{21} & b_{22}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\b_{21} & b_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

I'll spare the details, but after doing so for the $B$ given below, I got

B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\4 & 2\end{bmatrix}$\\4b-3c=0\\3a-3d=0\\4d-4a=0\\3c-4b=0$

and the RREF simplified to

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & -3/4 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

So then my line of thought is that, since there are two free variables, the solution to the system will consist of two linearly independent vectors, and therefore, the dimension of the kernel of $T$ will be $2$. However, this process is time consuming, so I was wondering if there is s simpler technique that I am overlooking.

Comment: Yes, there's a simpler technique. The answer doesn't change if you conjugate $B$, so you can try diagonalizing it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. The matrix B is always defined as the matrix given in the question. The matrix A is an arbitrary matrix.

Comment: Strictly speaking if the eigenvalues are nonreal you can't put into JNF over $\mathbb{R}$, so consider using rational canonical form or similar instead.

Comment: In general (if I remember correctly), the transformation over $M_n$ will have a kernel of dimension $n$ if and only if $B$ is non-derogatory, i.e. $B$ is [similar to a companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), i.e. $B$ has identical minimal and characteristic polynomials.  I think that this is the smallest possible dimension for the kernel.  The [Weyr canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyr_canonical_form) is convenient for these computations